# I'm having trouble making a javascript list on indeterminate length only display when certain attributes are assigned

Tags: javascript, attributes, hidden

I have a chatbox and I'm making a block function. I've pretty much got the code but it isn't working (Java isn't my language).

I've got the attribute and I can make it disappear but I cannot do it recursively. In many cases the code stops working altogether.

```
<table>
<td userclass="" username="cat">cat</td>
<td userclass="" username="hampster">hamster</td>
<td userclass="" username="dog">dog</td>
</table>

<p id="message"></p>

<script>
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
        var x = btn.attributes[1].value;

        if (x="hamster")
        {
          document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }else{
          document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.visibility = "visible";}
  }
</script>
```

Success occurs before I include the 'For' loop
Error usually doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Java is not javascript; check your supposed username attribute for "hamster" to "hampster" may that's the mistake

Comment: It's not, I put in "hampster" to supplant someones name. And your right - I shortened the name of the language but inadvertently used another language,

Comment: so what do think is doing, x = "hamster" ? , for me is a new value to this variable, should use a == or === for compare the string value, i think so;
the big problem is that var x, inside the for loop is replacing the scope, he's creating a new x var and then the .length of loop.. breaks down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` defines a variable in the global scope. You are using it to store the list of `<td>` and the value of an attribute. Try using different variable names first:

```
var myTds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myTds.length; i++) {
    var btn = myTds[i];
    var x = btn.attributes[1].value;

    if (x=="hamster") {
        myTds[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        myTds[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Also note that:

1) You should use `==` for comparisons;

2) you do not need to use `document.getElementsByTagName("td")`.

3) Change `username="hampster"` to `username="hamster"` in your HTML to see the example working.

JSBin [here](https://jsbin.com/daraqazike/edit?html,output)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LittleJohn Nice to know that it helped! :D Don't forget to accept the answer. That will make the community to know that the question was already answered.